# where can i download the rdf/owl/nt data files?

Tags: rdf

where can i download the rdf/owl/nt data files? (About the healthcare or medical rdf resource will be better)
I want to make use of the public RDF data files making some testing for SOR system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good Google term to help you search for available RDF datasets is `linked data`. For example, a list of freely available datasets which include downloadable RDF dumps is here:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/DataSetRDFDumps

linked from the index at [linkeddata.org](http://linkeddata.org/data-sets)

Comment: You should look at the data.gov datasets specifcally, there's a lot of health-related stuff in there.

Comment: As of 2021 the majority of those rdf download links are broken and that page is poorly maintained, if at all.

Answer (score 4):

A good place to start is the [CKAN](http://ckan.net/group/lodcloud) Data Hub, Linked Open Data (LOD) cloud, allows for topic-based browsing, informs about access methods (dump, SPARQL endpoint, etc.) and usage rights.

Answer (score 1):

Here Generate RDF and Instructions

http://webposible.com/utilidades/dublincore-metadata-gen/index.php?lang=en#resultados-metadatos